# How to integrate Maven and Github without third party services?

Tags: maven, github

I am currently using JitPack to access my GitHub repository via Maven. I used to love JitPack, but their servers seem to be overwhelmed, they have terrible technical support, so all in all I'd like to stop using it. Does anyone have a suggestion on what is a good way to achieve a similar result? In other words, I'd like to be able to push a change to my GitHub repo, tag it, and be able to use it in my maven builds immediately.

My follow up question is: why is there even a need for a third party server to host these jars? Is there any way to simply have maven pull these github repos, compile them locally, storing cache in ~/.m2, and that's it. For most of my development effort, this would be enough. I find myself constantly at the mercy of JitPack's crappy servers and poor service that drive me crazy.

Comment: Using central repository ?

Comment: Will a central repository update once I push my changes to GitHub?